# The best overloaded method match for ReadFile has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, I'm new to C# and copied this peace of code to read a specific part of a binary file, but I couldn't manage to fix it:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles;


namespace BinaryFileApplication
{
 class Program
    {


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        private static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
          uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
          uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern bool ReadFile(IntPtr hFile, [Out] byte[] lpBuffer,
           uint nNumberOfBytesToRead, out uint lpNumberOfBytesRead, IntPtr lpOverlapped);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

                        FileStream hFile = new FileStream("test.rex", FileMode.Open);
                        uint num = 24;
                        int timeFind = 0;
                        Array bytes;

                        ReadFile(hFile, (void*)(bytes), 24, &num, null);
                        timeFind = bytesToLong((byte*)(bytes), 0, 8);
                        Console.WriteLine("Time:", (int)timeFind);
                        return;

        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to fix the error?

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, use `FileStream`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry I didn't understand what should I do.

Comment: There is no point whatsoever in pinvoking ReadFile() when you can also call FileStream.Begin/Read().  Which pinvokes ReadFile.  There is never a point to it, you'd only ever consider pinvoking CreateFile() to bypass intentional FileStream limitations.  After which you'd use one of the FileStream(SafeFileHandle, ...) constructors.  And you still use FileStream.Begin/Read().